# Interact with several files in the same folder writing the path only once

Tags: shell

Consider that I'm in folder `X` and I want to *interact* with some files present in folder `Y`. I know there are infinite ways to do this, but what I am asking is specifically whether **this alternative** is possible:

```
<command> <path_to_Y>/[file1 file2 file3]
```

*e.g.*, I want to apply `command` to files `file1 file2 file3` which are present in `Y` by listing the path to `Y` only once, and by providing the file names in some sort of listing.

I'm pretty sure I've seen how to do this somewhere, but I couldn't find a way to search this specific method.

Comment: `Y/{file1,file2,file3}`, but that's not much of a programming question.

Comment: yeah this seems like more of a https://superuser.com/ question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use braces, as in:

```
<command> <path_to_Y>/{file1,file2,file3}
```

.. but YMMV according to which shell you're referring to.
Works in at least bash, csh and zsh.